# Spring Boot - merging map of map property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6 and have configuration properties as follows:

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
public class TestProperties {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> map;
    private Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> mapOfMaps;
}
```

and two yaml configuration files:

`application.yml`

```
test:
  map:
    1: 10
    2: 20
  mapOfMaps:
    KEY1:
      1: 10
      2: 20
    KEY2:
      3: 30
      4: 40
```

`application-dev.yml`

```
test:
  map:
    100: 100
  mapOfMaps:
    KEY1:
      100: 100
```

When I ran my application with `dev` profile I expected that both properties would contain only `dev` profile values (so basically an exact match of `application-dev.yml`).

Sample project is available here: https://github.com/poznachowski/spring-boot-mapmerge

For a simple `map` property it worked fine, but for a `mapOfMaps` property it resolves to `{KEY1={100=100}, KEY2={3=30, 4=40}}`.

Does that behave by design? If yes, is there a way to make it work in a way I described?

Answer (score 2):

This is working as designed. The application.yml can be seen as providing the default values for other profiles to override.

Essentially the base configuration will get merged with the profile that you enable, but the keys in the active profile will supersede those of the default.

[Spring Boot - Properties & configuration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment)

When I run your example with spring boot 1.5.6.RELEASE the resulting configuration object looks as follows:

```
test:
  map:
    1: 10
    2: 20
    100: 100
  mapOfMaps:
    KEY1:
      1:10
      2:20
      100:100
    KEY2:
      3: 30
      4: 40
```

If you wanted to have either the one or the other configuration active you would have to put the first in another application-{profile}.yml or make sure that you override every property in the default configuration.

Comment: What you are saying is not right. Here is the sample project: https://github.com/poznachowski/spring-boot-mapmerge

When you run it with dev profile you get exactly what I wrote:
`The following profiles are active: dev`. `map` -> `{100=100}` `mapOfMaps` -> `{KEY1={100=100}, KEY2={3=30, 4=40}}` What's more with lists it does not work this way (and it's explicitly stated in the documentation).

Comment: I think you might have stumbled onto a bug, where Spring does not handle numeric keys very well.  I think it is related to [SPR-13398](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13398?jql=project%20%3D%20SPR%20AND%20text%20~%20%22yaml%22). I've updated your sample to prove the point: https://github.com/johannbre/spring-boot-mapmerge.  As soon as you wrap the keys of your configuration entries in quotes, the code behaves as expected.

Comment: Also, this also only happens with YAML config. I tried this with property files and the code behaves as expected with no need to wrap keys in quotes.